# body background images change with fading using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using banner images in background of body `{background: url(banner1.jpg)}`

I have multiple image like banner1.jpg, banner2.jpg, banner3.jpg.

I want to change images automatically after specific interval like 5-10 seconds.

How to do this with jQuery? I don't want to use inline images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var images = ['banner1.jpg', 'banner2.jpg', 'banner3.jpg'];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('body').css('background-image', function() {
        if (i >= images.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')'; 
    });
}, 5000);
```

***UPDATE:***
If you want to change image smoothly, I suggest put all banner images into one image, and set it as body's background image, then use [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method with background-position to change the banner image.

Comment: What i will have to keep in css `body { background-image: url(../images/banner1.jpg)`?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working but I want to change images smoothly.

Comment: @JitendraVyas You can keep it, or set the css once use jquery at first.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `background-image` of the element:

```
$(elem).css('background-image', 'url(banner2.jpg)');
```

**EDIT** to fade in and out, you'll need to fade the container element:

```
$(elem).fadeOut('fast', function() {
     $(elem).css('background-image', 'url(banner2.jpg)')
         .fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: how images will change with fadein and out

Comment: Also note you have to preload the images for this to work in the first time pleople visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that this information is very useful and it works. I tried something different using JQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="bat"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#pic {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -98;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url ('http://wallpaperfast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Calm-sea-breeze-notebook-background-images-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg');
    display: none;
}
#bat {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -98;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg');
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#pic').css({
     height: $(window).height(),
     width: $(window).width()
 }).fadeIn('slow', function () {
     $('#pic').css('background-image', 'url(http://wallpaperfast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Calm-sea-breeze-notebook-background-images-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg)');
     $('#pic').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#pic').fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ymG9/)